# Update Statement with Join Duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

When performing an update using an INNER JOIN that results in duplication of records in the target table, what is the rule regarding which rows of the resulting table are taken as the records to be applied to the update?

For example:

T1:

```
|-------------|-------------|
|     col1    |     col2    |
|-------------|-------------|
|       1     |       A     |
|-------------|-------------|
|       1     |       B     |
|-------------|-------------|
|       1     |       C     |
|-------------|-------------|
```

T2:

```
|-------------|-------------|
|     col1    |     col2    |
|-------------|-------------|
|       1     |       D     |
|-------------|-------------|
|       1     |       E     |
|-------------|-------------|
|       1     |       F     |
|-------------|-------------|
```

Performing the following function results in all 3 rows in col2 of Table 1 being set to D.

```
UPDATE T1
SET col2 = T2.col2
FROM #TEMP T1 INNER JOIN #TEMP2 T2 ON T2.col1 = T2.col1
```

The code below illustrates the example:

```
SELECT 1 AS col1,'A' as col2 INTO #TEMP
INSERT INTO #TEMP
SELECT 1, 'B'
INSERT INTO #TEMP
SELECT 1, 'C'

SELECT 1 AS col1,'D' as col2 INTO #TEMP2
INSERT INTO #TEMP2
SELECT 1, 'E'
INSERT INTO #TEMP2
SELECT 1, 'F'

--SELECT * FROM #TEMP T1 INNER JOIN #TEMP2 T2 ON T2.col1 = T2.col1
--Result of below join

UPDATE T1
SET col2 = T2.col2
FROM #TEMP T1 INNER JOIN #TEMP2 T2 ON T2.col1 = T2.col1

SELECT * FROM #TEMP
```

Why is it that col2 of #TEMP takes the value D? Why not E or F?
Is this simply taken because it is the first record in the join?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks EzLo, I think that answers my question.

Answer (score 4):

I think the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#best-practices) is pretty clear on this matter.  I have bolded the most important parts:

> Use caution when specifying the FROM clause to provide the criteria
>   for the update operation.  **The results of an UPDATE statement are
>   undefined if the statement includes a FROM clause that is not
>   specified in such a way that only one value is available for each
>   column occurrence that is updated**, that is if the UPDATE statement is
>   not deterministic. For example, in the UPDATE statement in the
>   following script, both rows in Table1 meet the qualifications of the
>   FROM clause in the UPDATE statement; but it is undefined which row
>   from Table1 is used to update the row in Table2.

In other words, a value from an arbitrary matching row is used.  There is no rule as to which one.

A convenient way to set a particular value is to use `apply`:

```
UPDATE T1
    SET col2 = T2.col2
    FROM #TEMP T1 CROSS APPLY
         (SELECT TOP (1) t2.*
          FROM #TEMP2 T2 
          WHERE T2.col1 = T2.col1
          ORDER BY ?  -- this ordering specifies the prioritization for the assignment
         ) T2;
```

The `ORDER BY` specifies which row to use.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, much appreciated.